# How do I write the "script" bash command in a python script to log my output

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am trying to log my python output using bash command "script". The reason that I am doing this is because there is a piece of information that I needed from the program that I am running. But it is a Nonetype which was just printed in the console. I need that piece of information, but there is no way pulling this info out besides manually copy and paste it to my output file.

So I thought I can use "script" in bash to log everything in the console to a txt file and from there I kinda cheated and converted this Nonetype output in the console to a txt file. But now I am trying to make this process automatic. So I started testing this idea out, and I came across this issue: once the script reaches the line to call the "script" command, it spawns a new shell, so it was not able to reach the rest of the code.

Below is a piece of code for testing purpose.

```
from subprocess import call
call(['script', 'test.txt']) # call script in the bash shell
print('Hello World') # using python to print hello world
call(['exit']) # logout the shell
```

I am wondering is there any way that can call "script" command and return to the rest of the script?

Comment: It looks like there might be a simple answer to your question, but it's kind of hard to tell what you're trying to do. Could you provide a bit more context for your code and tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, it's really hard to describe. So basically, I am trying to log everything appears in the console to a txt file. Unfortunately, I don't have other codes at the moment besides the above one. Maybe there is another way beside using the "script" command?

Comment: That's what I suspect. If I'm correct, you have a non-Python program you want to get output from in a Python program. In that case, the documentation for `subprocess.call` refers to [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) if you want to capture the output of the subprocess.

Comment: `script` is not a "bash command", it is a program that resides on the filesystem like grep or sed or ...

Comment: No, it's a program run by python, and one of the command is a Nonetype. When running that command, it shows a table of information in the console. And I am trying to pull that table out. I don't have a lot of success since it is a Nonetype. 
And since it will show up in the console, I was thinking maybe I can use some bash shell commands to pull that out into a log file or something like that. And thank you for the correction on the subprocess.run

Comment: @YiJieTseng If this is a Python library or tool, you should check if they have a different way to invoke it so that you can get the information returned or written to your own stream, instead of printed to screen. They almost always do.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will contact the developer and ask them about it. By the way, I also figured out how to do solve my issue with "script"